# Omit database-calculated field from ADO.Net validation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, ado.net

Full disclaimer: I'm a total C# <-> DB noob.  I'm not bad at C#, and I'm not bad at Access, but integrating the two is new to me.

In my project, I'm using OleDB / ADO.Net (I guess -- honestly, I'm just taking the internet's word for it) and Visual Studio's built-in DataSource wizard to deal with an Access database.

Everything seems to [finally] be working okay, until I get to validation.  On validation, I believe the program tries to validate the DataSet against the DB, and that's where my error occurs -- I have a calculated field that doesn't seem to want to validate.

I would love to be able to exclude just that field from the pushed updates.

So my save code is this:

```
    private void saveDatabase()
    {
        this.Validate();
        this.standardizedPatientsBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.hSS_SPsDataSet);  
    }
```

When I validate, it throws this error:

```
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E21): Cannot update 'FullName'; field not updateable.
    [... a list of all the methods where it breaks, many of which are called behind the scenes...]
```

I know WHY it's not updateable -- it's a calculated field -- but what I can't figure out is how to ignore that field.

Comment: So, you're working with a strongly typed dataset, and this "FullName" column is defined on a DataTable in your DataSet ? And this column is a calculated field in the Access database ?

Comment: Correct.  And it's not even crucial to the table it's in -- it's there to make some of my bindings look better.  Ultimately, I think I'm just going to delete that field from the table and make a query to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will most likely have to manually edit the UpdateCommand (and also the InsertCommand) associated with the TableAdapter for said DataTable in your DataSet.

You can use the graphical query builder to remove the FullName field from the update and insert queries.

I'm not aware that this can be done automatically for Access calculated fields. I could be wrong though.

Cheers

Comment: I was afraid I would have to go this route (though I don't know why -- building an Access query and changing my binding in VS is going to be a lot faster than the time I've already spent trying to omit the field)... Thank you. :)

Comment: Please remember to mark the answer if it satisfies you. Cheers